# No libreoffice calc on a new install of Ubuntu Mate 22.04

Tags: package-management, libreoffice, 22.04

I recently did a fresh install of Ubuntu Mate 22.04. Libreoffice calc is missing.
The version in the repository is `libreoffice-calc 1:7.3.2-0ubuntu2`, but when I try  `sudo apt-get install libreoffice-calc`, I get

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-calc : Depends: libreoffice-base-core (= 1:7.3.2-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:7.3.2-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
```

On inspection, libreoffice-(base-)core is at version `1:7.3.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1`; It looks like the only libreoffice-calc reachable from the repository in 22.04 is an older version incompatible with the rest of libreoffice? How would one fix this?

#### Edit, answering the comments:

This was a clean install of Ubuntu Mate 22.04 from a few weeks ago (I ran into some frustrating problems with Ubuntu Studio 22.04 and nuked the installation). I don't recall whether there were options for a "light" vs "full" install, or which I might have selected if this was an option. I've added some software, but nothing that should obviously touch `libreoffice-core` (It looks like we just need to find the `1:7.3.4` version of calc and the repo is seeing `1:7.3.2`)

Someone asked for the full output of `sudo apt update`.

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease                      
Hit:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu jammy InRelease                      
Hit:4 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/savoury1/chromium/ubuntu jammy InRelease       
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

Comment: Maybe (I'm guessing here) `gnumeric` is bundled with Ubuntu MATE. It is a light-weight alternative. In my Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS, Libreofffice Calc is bundled by default, so it should be available. `$ LANG=C apt-cache policy libreoffice-calc
libreoffice-calc:
  Installed: 1:7.3.5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  Candidate: 1:7.3.5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1` so it seems you have not an up to date version.

Comment: It could be a temporary problem due to a lot of not yet synchronized updated packages due to preparation for the release of 22.04.1 (the first point release). If you try with `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` a few times in the near future, I think you will solve the problem.

Comment: @sudous: Thanks! `gnumeric` handles ODS well enough, with some errors; Perhaps I will switch to this ( :

Comment: @user535733: Did my edit provide the requested information?

Comment: Try `sudo apt install libreoffice`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `apt update` output shows that you have disabled the `jammy-updates` pocket of the Ubuntu Repositories.

Turn `jammy-updates` back on. Then `libreoffice-calc` will install properly.

[image: Software & Updates Window]